# Character encoding issue when extracting data in Keen

Tags: character-encoding, keen-io

What character encoding should I use when addings events to Keen ?

Whenever I use international characters (e.g. ö / ë) , they are stored fine (when I look in the event explorer).

But whenever I use them in reports or the data explorer,  they get mangled.

[image: Event]

[image: data explorer]

Answer (score 0):

It seems this problem has been fixed over the last couple of days.  Awesome!

Comment: Just FYI, your post on StackOverflow just might have prompted an investigation into this issue, which led to that fix...